# Condicional para executar instrução sql

Tags: postgresql

No SQL Server posso usar um `'if'` para verificar se determinada tabela possui uma coluna e dependendo do retorno dessa função lógica, executar ou não uma instrução, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('MINHA_TABELA', 'MINHA_COLUNA') IS NULL
  BEGIN
    PRINT N'ALTER MINHA_TABELA RENAME COLUMN MINHA_COLUNA'
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MINHA_TABELA] ADD [MINHA_COLUNA] [INT] NULL;
  END
GO
```

Tentei achar algo parecido para Postgres e não consegui, alguém sabe como fazer algo parecido nesse tipo de banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da mesma forma. O Postgres aceita, por exemplo:

```
IF ... THEN

IF ... THEN ... ELSE

IF ... THEN ... ELSIF ... THEN ... ELSE
```

Um exemplo de `If` é:

```
IF parentid IS NULL OR parentid = ''
THEN
    RETURN fullname;
ELSE
    RETURN hp_true_filename(parentid) || '/' || fullname;
END IF;
```

[Clique aqui para ler a documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-control-structures.html). Tem todos os tipos de exemplos possíveis.